# How to test if a sequence contains a new line characters within a certain window length in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have this list in Python:

```
my_list = ["KKAWTMYGNLSKKDQNRYNA\nDAT", # false
           "EEQLLNEPD\nKIVIIPACVIDELEENKKLKGLEEILKKVRRA", #true
           "NNCLQKYKEAEEYYEESIFILKTVN", # false
           "EEQLLNEPD\nKIVIIPACV\nIDELEENKKLKGLEEILKKVRRA", #true
           "NNCLQKYKEAEEYY\nEESIFILKTVN", # false
        ]
```

I'd like a function to detect if the given string has "\n" (new line) characters within the 10 characters window.

At the end of the day, only two strings satisfy that:

```
"EEQLLNEPD\nKIVIIPACVIDELEENKKLKGLEEILKKVRRA", #true
"EEQLLNEPD\nKIVIIPACV\nIDELEENKKLKGLEEILKKVRRA", #true
```

I'm stuck with this code that doesn't do the job.

```
def has_newline_within_window(s, window=10):
    for i in range(len(s) - window):
        if "\n" in s[i:i + window]:
            return True
    return False

my_list = ["KKAWTMYGNLSKKDQNRYNA\nDAT", # false
           "EEQLLNEPD\nKIVIIPACVIDELEENKKLKGLEEILKKVRRA", #true
           "NNCLQKYKEAEEYYEESIFILKTVN", # false
           "EEQLLNEPD\nKIVIIPACV\nIDELEENKKLKGLEEILKKVRRA", #true
           "NNCLQKYKEAEEYY\nEESIFILKTVN", # false
        ]

for sequence in my_list:
    if has_newline_within_window(sequence):
        print(sequence)
```

Please advice, how can I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing here is sliding the window from the start to the end of the string, hence if '\n' is present in the string it will return True.

If you just want to check if the '\n' character is in the first 10 characters (where 10 here is the window length), then replace your function with this one:

```
def has_newline_within_window(s, window=10):
    for i in range(window):
        if '\n'==s[i]:
            return True
    return False
```

Also to print the results you need to replace '\n' in the string with '\\n', i.e., you need to escape the escape character.

Therefore, while printing the sequence replace `print(sequence)` with `print(sequence.replace("\n","\\n"))`

Now the whole code will look like this:

```
def has_newline_within_window(s, window=10):
for i in range(window):
    if '\n'==s[i]:
        return True
return False


my_list = ["KKAWTMYGNLSKKDQNRYNA\nDAT",  # false
           "EEQLLNEPD\nKIVIIPACVIDELEENKKLKGLEEILKKVRRA",  # true
           "NNCLQKYKEAEEYYEESIFILKTVN",  # false
           "EEQLLNEPD\nKIVIIPACV\nIDELEENKKLKGLEEILKKVRRA",  # true
           "NNCLQKYKEAEEYY\nEESIFILKTVN",  # false
           ]

for sequence in my_list:
    if has_newline_within_window(sequence):
        print(sequence.replace("\n","\\n"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can slice the input string up to the `window`-th character and test if there is a newline character in it:

```
def has_newline_within_window(s, window=10):
    return '\n' in s[:window]
```

Comment: this only check for the _first_ 10aa windows, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Combined with the method of playing home, it should be like this in the end:

```py
def has_newline_within_window(s, window=10):
    return "\n" in s[:window]


for index, i in enumerate(my_list):
    if has_newline_within_window(i):
        print(i.replace("\n", "\\n"))
```